# search query for friend wont work correct way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

I am trying to make a search friend system like facebook, but I have a problem with result. The results not showing friends it will show all data  with two times.

I have made this query :

```
$uid = '1';
$key = 'john'
$result = mysqli_query($this->db,"
SELECT U.username,U.userid,U.userfullname, F.userone, F.usertwo, F.role 
FROM users U, friends F WHERE U.username like '%$key' OR  
 U.userfullname like '$key%' OR  U.username like '$key%' OR  
 U.userfullname like '%$key' OR U.username like '$key' OR  
 U.userfullname like '$key'  AND F.userone=U.userid AND 
 F.userone='$uid' AND F.role='fri' AND F.userone = '$uid' 
 ORDER BY F.userone = '$uid' LIMIT 10") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

User Data Table,

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `userfullname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL, 
  `userstatus` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`, `username`, `userfullname`,`userstatus`) VALUES
(1, 'john', 'John Doe', '0'),
(2, 'aziz', 'aziz', '0'),
(3, 'selma', 'Selma Kose', '0');
```

friends Table

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `friendid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usertwo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` enum('flwr','fri') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  PRIMARY KEY (`friendid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


INSERT INTO `friends` (`friendid`, `userone`, `usertwo`, `role`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'me'),
(2, 2, 2, 'me'),
(3, 3, 3, 'me'),
(4, 2, 1, 'fri'),
(5, 2, 3, 'flwr'),
(6, 3, 1, 'fri');
```

Please think you are searching your friends and your user id is 1 and you are searching aziz the query checking aziz is your friend (`fri or flwr`) from friends table if yes then show result. But my query showing all users not just friends.

What I am missing here anyone can help me in this regard ?

The result must be just for john username but it is showing all users with two times.

Here is a **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d6ee/9)**

Comment: `AND` has priority over `OR`. Did you try using `( )` around your conditions?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes i have tryed but giving empty result.

Comment: Can you detail what meaning you define for `userone` and `usertwo` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT U.username userone, UT.username usertwo, F.role FROM friends F 
JOIN users U ON F.userone = U.userid
JOIN users UT ON F.usertwo = UT.userid
WHERE 
UT.username = 'john' AND F.userone = 1 
AND (F.role = 'fri' OR F.role = 'flwr')
```

It will return all friends of user with id=2, which name is `john`.

[DEMO](http://%20sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d6ee/26)

Comment: @michael-turczyn Can you show me your working answer from here please , http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d6ee/2

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, i write wrong username. It should be John searcher aziz and serching userid is 1

Comment: i am working on your answer but i can not get a result like yours. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d6ee/14

Comment: It's not your answer, but I use query in your answer.

Comment: Ok, but it must be show just F.role = 'fri' OR F.role = 'flwr' I have tryed it but it is swohing also role ='me'  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d6ee/23

Comment: Your query in your answer is showing correct result but i can not get correct result when i try to search friend in my original query can you please answer me using my query ?

Comment: @Azzo Your query DOES NOT work. That's why I posted different query, so your requirment is met. It is not possible "answer uisng your query". What does that even mean? Do you want working query or your query, which doesn't work? If you want your query, why did you even ask the question?